# SwiftUI remove color of selected item in List with rounded corners (MacOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to make a Sidebar with a bunch of NavigationLinks, to switch between pages of my App. I'm very happy with the current design, the only thing that bothers me is the accent color when I select a Link. That Pink is my system Accent, and it even stays when I give the App a custom accent.

[image]

This is my current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Int? = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List((0...10), id: \.self, selection: $selection) {i in
                NavigationLink(destination: hmm()){
                    HStack {
                        Image("linuxIcon")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 40.0)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text("IP: 192.168.1.1").font(.headline)
                            Text("Linux 5.5.10").font(.subheadline)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .padding(.trailing, 5.0)
                            .padding(.bottom, 0)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }.background(Color.gray.clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(8))
                }.tag(i).frame(height: 40)
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried `.listRowBackground` but it has the same issue.
I'm a complete newbie and beginner with SwiftUI, and I am very grateful for every tip and code improvement ;)